# Iterating through tensors in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have two 1D tensors. One is a vector of predictions, second is vector of labels. I am trying to write a loop that checks the element-wise difference between vectors. If such diff is spotted, I want to do another operation, for simplicity let's say I want to print ("Diff spotted"). So far I came up with this but I got an error: Expected object of scalar type Byte but got scalar type Float for argument #2 'other'. I would appreciate help here. Maybe there is some more efficient way to do it, without loop.

```
for i in enumerate(t1):
    if t1[i] != t2[i]:
        print("Diff spotted")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `eq()` function in pytorch to check if to tensors are the same element-wise. For every index of an element which is the same as the labels element you get a `True`:

```
for label in predictions.round().eq(labels):
    for element in label:
        if element == False:
            print("Diff spotted!")
```